# Can I use blocking TCP Socket.Send in a server loop?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

If one of the sockets blocks Send() it can affect other client(s). I am worried about that: does Send() waits for the "delivered" answer? If it is than a remote client can block my server events processing loop by ignoring incoming packets - then I should use BeginSend. But I've measured that BeginSend eats more CPU. So I want to know weather it's acceptable to use blocking Send in the server events loop?

As the MSDN states

> The successful completion of a send does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered.

I know that socket can also block when its send buffer becomes filled.

Comment: `But I've measured that BeginSend eats more CPU` I would like to see how you measured it.

Comment: I replaced Send with BeginSend in my network engine load tests to check it. 2000 clients send and receive one packet every 200 ms while the server simultanously spams random packets to them (to simulate n^n small relevant sets load). Send shows 14-15% of server CPU load, BeginSend shows 17-18%. Sorry, I can't send you my network code because it's very big and complicated assembly :)

Comment: @L.B You may think that 3-4% is not a sensable overhead but the server is a performance critical application and I want to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: @L.B You don't think the same? Let's just *compare*. 18/15. It's 20% performance overhead. Now it look like a problem, yeah?

Comment: I also don't think your tests are correct. See my very first comment. I tried to imply it in a polite way.

Comment: @L.B May be it's not measured independently like you want but for me, in my environment, BeginSend is comparable slow. So it makes sense, at least for me, to use Send if it's avaliable.

Comment: you seem to be determined to use your approach, then use it, but don't expect us to say *you are on the right track*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one of the sockets blocks Send() it can affect other client(s).

Only if your server is single-threaded. Solution: multi-threading.

> I am worried about that: does Send() waits for the "delivered" answer?

No, but it can block if the client isn't reading and the buffers fill up.

> If it is than a remote client can block my server events processing loop by ignoring incoming packets - then I should use BeginSend. But I've measured that BeginSend eats more CPU. So I want to know weather it's acceptable to use blocking Send in the server events loop?

No it isn't. Use multi-threading, or non-blocking I/O, or Async I/O if you can overcome your aversion. Your suggestion of 3-4% overhead doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: "it can block if the client isn't reading" - can you provide more information on this?

Comment: I already **use** async IO for receiving. What the "aversion"? I use multi-threading but I look at how fast it executes and make improvements where single-threading can be more suitable or other optimization. If you not optimize your network core like this you won't reach even 200 clients limit for realtime network games. Each percent does matter.

Comment: @Vlad What I understand from your question and comments is that you are not asking anything, but expect an approval for your approach. Sorry, I don't think the same.

Comment: "No, but it can block if the client isn't reading and the buffers fill up." Can I somehow determinate how much is buffer filled?

Comment: If you use non-blocking I/O you will know when you get EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, and if you use multithreading you don't need to know. My point about your aversion to using Async for writing is that I don't believe your overhead figures. I'd like to see the code you used to determine it.

Comment: @L.B I am trying to keep the Send() approach but I am willing to consider the async way if it's only the available solution. If you can refute my approach I'll consider that. The question is about weather I can keep using Send or not.

Comment: @Vlad `If you can refute my approach I'll consider that` No I won't try anything to refute. It is your problem/question not mine. BTW: Either use your question or this answer to comment. It is hard to follow your comments.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I'll use non blocking sockets with Send approach. I think the async IO overhead is related to thread pooling and callback costs.